# Apache Permission Error on open file in Python

Tags: python, php, apache, lamp, centos8

I am new to web design, and I'm trying to setup an Apache web interface to some python code.
I am running a test python script that just opens a new file in /var/www/html/ called output.txt and attempts to write to it. When the web page is loaded, I use `shell_exec('/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/ptest.py');` to run my python script. The python script does run and outputs some print messages, but trying to open output.txt fails with:
*Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/www/html/ptest.py", line 8, in f=open("/var/www/html/output.txt", "w") PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/html/output.txt'*. It will also fail if the file already exists and I open to read.

I have confirmed that the script is being run by apache with `getpass.getuser()`, and I have tried as many different permission combinations as I can think of for /var/www/html/, including 777. I have set apache as the group for every directory from /var/ to html/. I have tried creating the file ahead of time with 777 permissions. I have checked that /var/ to html/ has group execution permission.
I have tried creating and using another folder completely owned by apache.

I have looked through the apache directives to see if there is a directive I need to have, but I haven't found one yet.

I've included the code for my python script and my php page below.

EDIT: I've tried running ptest.py as apache using `su -s /bin/bash apache`.

ptest.py successfully runs this way, so the problem doesn't seem to be a permission associated with the apache user/group.

ptest.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import getpass
import os
sys.stderr = sys.stdout
print(getpass.getuser())
print(os.getgid())
f = open("/var/www/html/output.txt", "w")
f.write("banana")
f.close()
print("I wrote banana, which is a berry")
```

banana.php

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h2>Welcome to the Program Test</h2>
        <?php
            echo "Created Command", "<br>";
            $output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/ptest.py');
            echo "Executed Command", "<br>";
            echo $output, "<br>";
            echo "End of output", "<br>";
            $output = shell_exec('ls /var/www/html/');
            echo $output;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like typical selinux problem. Try `selinux setenforce 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to [domino_pl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6700213/domino-pl) leaving a comment.

> It looks like typical selinux problem. Try selinux setenforce 0 – [domino_pl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6700213/domino-pl)